# Simple note app always available with hotkey

Tags: note-taking, macos

My workflow:
During the day I neet to write down some short disposable notes. 
Requirements:

- With an hotkey open a textedit area (plain or markdown even better)
- No need to create new *files* one single long textfile is enough
- No need to "save with name", the archive can be inside the app.

The app must run on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found something that covers my requirements: [Unclutter](https://unclutterapp.com).

It has some functionalities that I don't need, but it's a nice scrapbook app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Note app that comes with the system. This app appears in the doc so is always one click away. I use the app frequently. I open a new note page then minimize the app. Whenever I need to make a note I click the app in the doc and it appears with my page visible. You can also select a word or phrase, right click it, and do an internet search on it.

Comment: I know, all the apps I know can have the same behavior but what I'm looking for is slightly different (see my answer)